# plyr + simpleboot: NA in probability vector

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, statistics-bootstrap

I am using `simpleboot`package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simpleboot/index.html) to obtain confidence intervals.

This is my function:

```
lb_weighted_median_dplyr <- function(x,v) {
  set.seed(1234)
  b <- one.boot(x, weights = v, FUN = function(x,w) matrixStats::weightedMedian(x, w = v, na.rm = TRUE), R = 100, student = FALSE)
  round(perc(b, 0.025), 0)
}
```

What the function does is to calculate the lower bound of the confidence interval when I run

```
ddply(wage_by_gender_2015, .(sex,region), summarise, FUN = lb_weighted_median_dplyr(wage, exp_region))
```

Where `wage` is a numeric column and `exp_region` is another numeric column that contains weights.

I don't have data for some regions, therefore the function fails with some regions and returns

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : NA in probability vector
```

How can I bypass that error and obtain NA as the lower bound for a region without data?

A `dplyr` equivalent approach that also returns `NA in probability vector` is

```
grouped <- group_by(wage_by_gender_2015, sex, region)
dplyr::summarise(grouped, FUN = lb_weighted_median_dplyr(wage, exp_region))
```

Relevant sample of the data here: http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~mvargas/casen/wage_by_gender_2015.RData

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput()`

Comment: You say dplyr, but use a plyr function...

Comment: what do you mean? that writes an ASCII text

Comment: `ddply` is from plyr

Comment: sorry, fixing now

Comment: Your data... wage_by_gender_2015? Where's the `dput()` of it? To meet the Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example requirement the `r` tag description indicates that the data should be `dput()` in the question or provided as a built in dataset. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: that's gonna be slow I'm afraid :S I can create a dump of the relevant part

Comment: @pachamaltese You don't have to (and almost never should) use your actual, large data set. You need a minimal, complete, verifiable example. It can be made up data that represents your real data or a sample of it.

Comment: here's a relevant sample http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~mvargas/casen/wage_by_gender_2015.RData

Comment: Thank you much. I can answer your question with some data I made up but that sample is missing sex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wage_by_gender_2015 <- data.frame(sex    = rep(c("male", "female"),100),
                                  region = rep(c("north", "south", "east",
                                                 "west"), 50),
                                  exp_region = abs(rnorm(100)),
                                  wage       = abs(rnorm(100))
)

wage_by_gender_2015$exp_region[10] <- NA
ddply(wage_by_gender_2015, .(sex,region), summarise, FUN = lb_weighted_median_dplyr(wage, exp_region))
```

> ```
>  Error in sample.int(length(x), replace = TRUE, ...) :    NA in probability vector
> ```

```
# impute
wage_by_gender_2015$exp_region <- RRF::na.roughfix(wage_by_gender_2015$exp_region)

ddply(wage_by_gender_2015, .(sex,region), summarise, FUN = lb_weighted_median_dplyr(wage, exp_region))
```

> ```
>     sex region FUN
> 1 female  south   0
> 2 female   west   0
> 3   male   east   1
> 4   male  north   0
> ```

As mentioned in the comment I would've used your sample data but it was missing `sex`.

Comment: thanks... yes, a stupid error of mine 
updating the sample now

Comment: I updated my sample now and I'm testing your solution with the full dataset
thanks a lot :)

Comment: @pachamaltese You're welcome, let me know if you have any problem

Comment: that approach is clever !! replacing NAs by the median allows to do inference 

I did check my full dataset and my weights are ranged [1,1699] without NAs and I still have that error :S ... I'm gonna try again

Comment: @pachamaltese If you post the code where you imputed and still got that error then I can debug it. By the way, there are more advanced types of imputation such as Amelia II, but it's usually not worth the time and effort to do them.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hack-R ... I did restart the computer and it worked :S